# ThreadPool and displaying info without form freezing

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have one problem. In my project i need for more then 100 threads, that's why i prefer to use ThreadPool. here is a part of code, but in this case i have got a lot of memory usage and my form is very laggy, cuz of A lot of BeginInvoke calls(i suppose).
Is there any solutions for this problem?

```
  public void launch()
    {
        while (data.Count > 0)
        {
            string[] part;
            if (data.Count> 1000)
            {
                part = data.Take(1000).ToArray();
                data = data.Skip(1000).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                part = data.Take(data.Count).ToArray(); data = data.Skip(1000).ToList();
            }
            foreach (var input in part)
            {
                try
                {
                    char splitter = ':';
                    if (input.Contains(';')) splitter = ';';
                    string login = input.Split(splitter)[0];
                    string pass = input.Split(splitter)[1];
                EncryptCore ec = new EncryptCore(new byte[15]);
                PacketSend ps = new PacketSend(ec, "");
                ps._login = login;
                ps._password = pass;
                ps.Brutted+=ps_Parsed;
                ps.Failed+=ps_Failed;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ps.Parse);
                }
                catch { Interlocked.Increment(ref curr); }


            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
        data.Clear();
    }

 private void ps_Brutted(User Account)
    {
        toGet.Add(Account);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref good);
        goodLabl.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
        {
            goodLabl.Text = "Good: " + good;
        }));
      Update();
    }
private void Update()
    {
        try
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref curr);

            progLabel.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                progLabel.Text = (double.Parse(curr.ToString()) / double.Parse(max.ToString())).ToString("#%");
            }));
            progressBar.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                progressBar.Text = (double.Parse(curr.ToString()) / double.Parse(max.ToString()) * 100).ToString("#");
            }));
            checkedLabl.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                checkedLabl.Text = "Checked: " + curr + " / " + max;
            }));
        }
        catch { }


    }
```

Comment: What makes you think you need 100 threads? And, yes, if you have lots of calls to `BeginInvoke`, then the UI thread will be busy servicing those updates and won't be able to service the user's actions.

Comment: How can i fix that?
I'm trying to use timer which update info eevery 3 seconds, but form is still freezing.

Comment: You haven't given me enough information to say. I don't know what your `ps.Parse` method is doing, but I strongly suspect you don't want dozens of them going concurrently. Also, rather than making three separate calls to `BeginInvoke` to update your three controls, write a single method that updates the controls and make one `BeginInvoke` call to that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have thousands of tasks, and each time one of them completes you update the UI by scheduling 4 updates on the UI thread.  What you might consider doing is having the UI update on a timer-based schedule (try 100ms or 200ms) based on the integers that are updating.

Aside from that, you've got some strange numeric operations going on.  You can just cast an `int` to a `double`, you don't have to round-trip through a `String`.

Comment: U mean that this conversion of types and timer can fix this freezes?

Comment: Maybe.  There isn't enough information here for anyone to reproduce the problem, so they are educated guesses.